# Espacio entre los elementos. Bootstrap

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

estoy conociendo el mundo de bootstrap.

Me mandaron a realizar una práctica sencilla, pero siempre termino con el mismo problema. **La separación entre elementos.** A continuación les mostraré mi inquietud, quizás es una tontería pero quisiera ayuda con ello, se los agradecería, gracias. La meta es la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">    
        <nav class="col-sm-12 navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username...">
                    </div>
                </form>
        </nav>
        <br>
        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-sm-4 alert alert-primary">
                <strong>
                    Prueba de componente alert
                </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 alert alert-secondary">
                <strong>
                    Prueba de componente alert
                </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 alert alert-success">
                <strong>
                    Prueba de componente alert
                </strong>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-sm-4 alert alert-danger">
                <strong>
                    Prueba de componente alert
                </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 alert alert-warning">
                <strong>
                    Prueba de componente alert
                </strong>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 alert alert-info">
                <strong>
                    Prueba de componente alert
                </strong>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-sm-6 alert alert-light">
                <strong>
                    Prueba de componente alert
                </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 alert alert-dark ">
                <strong>
                    Prueba de componente alert
                </strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>       
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>       
<script src="js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>      
</html>
```

Pero por desgracia, obtengo totalmente lo contrario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté disminuyendo el espacio entre columnas, pero no es lo que quiero, se ve muy pequeño, muy encogido. Y sin embargo, cuando intento escribir más se sale del *alert*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que los estilos de la clase `alert` se los estas aplicando a los div con la clase `col`, lo que podrías hacer es crear un elemento `div` dentro de cada elemento con la clase `col` y añadirle los estilos `alert`, te pongo un ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <nav class="col-sm-12 navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark mb-3">
  <form class="form-inline">
   <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
    <input type="text" class="form control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username...">
   </div>
  </form>
 </nav>
 <div class="container">

  <div class="row justify-content-between">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="alert alert-primary">
     <strong>Prueba de componente alert</strong>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="alert alert-secondary">
     <strong>Prueba de componente alert</strong>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="alert alert-success">
     <strong>Prueba de componente alert</strong>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-between">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class=" alert alert-danger">
     <strong>Prueba de componente alert</strong>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
     <strong>Prueba de componente alert</strong>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
     <strong>Prueba de componente alert</strong>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-between">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="alert alert-light">
     <strong>Prueba de componente alert</strong>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="alert alert-dark">
     <strong>Prueba de componente alert</strong>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema radica en la distribución entre los row y col que estas intentando implementar. Estas muy cerca, sólo debes ajustar un poco la distribución de los elementos

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="col-sm-12 navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark mb-3">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
      <input type="text" class="form control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username...">
    </div>
  </form>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="alert alert-primary">
        <strong>
          Prueba de componente alert
        </strong>
      </div>
      
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>
          Prueba de componente alert
        </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="alert alert-secondary">
        <strong>
          Prueba de componente alert
        </strong>
      </div>
      
      <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <strong>
          Prueba de componente alert
        </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <strong>
          Prueba de componente alert
        </strong>
      </div>
      
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <strong>
          Prueba de componente alert
        </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="alert alert-light">
        <strong>
          Prueba de componente alert
        </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="alert alert-dark">
        <strong>
          Prueba de componente alert
        </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Te dejo **[este](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)** link para que le eches un vistazo y entiendas mejor como trabajan las columnas en Bootstrap ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a agregar un div padre para cada alert y asi puedas controlar el margin y padding del elemento.

Asi con **pr-1 pl-1** al div se le agrega padding derecho e izquierdo respectivamente.

```
 <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-sm-4 pr-1 pl-1">
            <div class=" alert alert-primary">
                <strong>
                    Prueba de componente alert
                </strong>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 pr-1 pl-1">
            <div class=" alert alert-primary">
                <strong>
                    Prueba de componente alert
                </strong>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 pr-1 pl-1">
            <div class=" alert alert-primary">
                <strong>
                    Prueba de componente alert
                </strong>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Siempre toma en cuenta las diferencias que existen entre el border, el margin y el padding.
[image: Distribucion de elemento html]

Margin: La distancia que mantiene un elemento de otro

Padding: La distancia que mantienen los elementos dentro del mismo elemento. En este caso del div padre agregamos un padding para obtener el espacio requerido del alert.

Border: Grosor o anchura de un elemento.

Comment: Perfecto ¡Gracias!